# Connect Pi4 to TV Hitachi (mid 2000's) HDMI

Tags: hdmi, pi-4, connection

trying to connect Pi4 to a Hitachi TV (pretty old - mid 2000's), however it has the HDMI port. So my Pi4 is connected.

SD card is with OS's on it.

Any idea why Pi4 is not booting up? I have selected a PC channel on TV.

Thank you.

Comment: Which OS how did you flash it? Suggest flashing Raspbian Buster with Desktop direct to sd card with Etcher. You may then need to force your TV resolution in /boot/config.txt.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what you mean by flashing Raspbian Buster. In regards to forcing resolution, there is no config file in OS's folders. I reformatted the Sd card and uploaded NOOBS to it via copy/paste from the RP website download.      https://i.postimg.cc/qM3CMc0R/Screenshot-2020-05-01-at-13-02-29.png

Comment: Maybe the Raspberry Pi imager would be easier https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Comment: Thanks, will I be able to install the rest of the OS's after?

Comment: I installed Imager, still the same, no connection made. Will have to email Pi org. Thanks

Comment: So did you use imager to flash Raspbian onto an sd card? Are you using the hdmi next to the power connection?

Comment: i did, yes. Thank you for the tips. yeah, HDMI is next to the power. Cheers

Comment: Ok, its getting a bit of a pain getting the Pi to display :) 
Tried to uncomment some HDMI settings in the `config` file. Tried all of the options below: 

`#hdmi_safe=1` `#hdmi_force_hotplug=1` `#hdmi_group=1` `#hdmi_mode=1` `#hdmi_drive=2` `#config_hdmi_boost=4` `#sdtv_mode=2` running out of pptions here :)

Comment: What resolution is your TV?

Comment: Old one :) 1366 x 768 - Full specs: http://www.hitachidigitalmedia.com/en-gb/discontinued-products/led-tvs/32-81cm/32ld6600

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in /boot/config.txt:

```
# force HDMI
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
# disable EDID
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
# DMT group
hdmi_group=2
# 1366x768 60Hz 16:9
hdmi_mode=81
```

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

Comment: Thank you @CoderMike. Still no luck with these settings. Tried other ones too. Tried as well https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom/releases/tag/v2020.04.16-137ad It looks likeit could be the issuewith the Pi itself, as I do not even get any flashing green LED light when trying to boot up. Thank you for the effort on help.

Comment: What power supply are you using? Do you see a constant red led?

Comment: Yes, it is a constant red LED. https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Micro-USB-Type-C-Power-Supply-Adapter-Charger-for-Raspberry-Pi-4B-DC-5V-3A/184210133573?_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20180105095853%26meid%3D389f406ee6724fe8ba30fa1c28e3b235%26pid%3D100903%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D14%26mehot%3Dnone%26sd%3D303284569706%26itm%3D184210133573%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2510209%26brand%3DUnbranded&_trksid=p2510209.c100903.m5276

Comment: What size sd card are you using? Maybe try using Etcher to flash as it verifies? https://www.balena.io/etcher/ I'm out of ideas, this is the official won't boot thread https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151

Comment: This mentions your odd resolution not working on a Pi4, might be worth you commenting on the post https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=266797

Comment: Cheers @CoderMike, will have to fully investigate this, will let you know if success. Your effort is greatly appreciated.